# Were any external disk drives stacked vertically?

Tags: hardware, floppy-disk, disk-drive

There was a time when floppy disk drives were big, expensive devices that in many cases, instead of being components of a computer, would be separate machines connected by a cable, in some cases with their own CPU. A well-known example was the Commodore 1541, which had a similar CPU to the Commodore 64.

I personally only ever had one external drive, but when you look at photographs of setups with two drives (very desirable if you could afford it), they are always side-by-side, taking up an awful lot of desk space. Even the CBM 4040 dual drive, places the drives side-by-side in a single very wide case.

It seems to me that since disk drives are fundamentally horizontal devices that want to be wide rather than tall, the obvious solution would be to stack them vertically. Maybe this would result in each drive picking up heat and vibration from the other one, but if this was tolerable when they were stacked vertically in a PC tower case, why not for external drives?

Were external disk drives ever stacked vertically? If not, why not?

Comment: Since there is no reason to prefer any orientation, this question asks for opinions about design, thus not realy OT at all.

Comment: @Raffzahn and here we agree ;) Any orientation is allowed on floppies except upside-down...

Comment: @Raffzahn I asked whether external disk drives were in fact ever stacked vertically (historical fact), and if not, why not - the intent of that part was whether there was some technical reason why not. As it turns out, the answer is yes, there were lots of vertically stacked disk drives, so it resolves to a matter of historical fact, not opinion at all.

Comment: @rwallace The fault in your argumentation is _assuming that an external case is anything but a case_ - no difference here, thus no base to differentiate. A case is a case is a case.

Comment: I would be worried about knocking over a pair of full-height drives stacked one atop each other. So my guess is that the reason was mechanical stability. This issue goes away with half height floppy drives.

Comment: @tofro, "Any orientation is allowed on floppies except upside-down" - And here, I will disagree, as upside-down is certainly a valid orientation for floppies. In fact, back in the day, I cut notches into quite a number of floppies so I could put them in upside-down and double my storage capacity.

Comment: Why not?  Because racks are 19" wide  :-)

Comment: How many do you think you can stack:  https://www.ibm.com/ibm/history/exhibits/storage/storage_1301.html

Comment: @GlenYates I guess you turned the disk upside down and not the drive?

Comment: @tofro Why wouldn't the drives work upside down?

Comment: @Xen2050 Mechanically, I'd guess they'd work fine - It's more about dust protection that dust may fall where designers didn't think of. In 3 1/2" drives the springs that press the disk upwards when ejecting are designed to work *against* gravity, not *with* it

Comment: Apple II drives where usually side-by-side when below the monitor (because stacking them vertically below the monitor doesn't work - to unstable), and stacked vertically when next to the computer.

Comment: We used to stack our external CBM drives when we had several versions hooked up to our PET's - just changed the GIBP address

Comment: I recall using vertical 8" floppies on IBM S/32, S/34 and S/36

Comment: [Of course there were vertically-stacked disk drives](http://history.cs.ncl.ac.uk/anniversaries/40th/images/ibm360_672/slide20.jpg).  And horizontally too, at the same time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> It seems to me that since disk drives are fundamentally horizontal devices that want to be wide rather than tall,

To me they are taller than wide. After all, that's as well the orientation IBM did put the very first drive, so anything else is plain wrong, isn't it :))

> the obvious solution would be to stack them vertically.

That's pure opinion and up to the designer how he imagines a drive to look best or fit best. The drives itself work in any orientation with any angle equally well.

> It seems to me that since disk drives are fundamentally horizontal devices

As said before, they are not, they work in any orientation. At least as long as we talk about the technology. If at all, any orientation can come from ball bearing involved. Except, for simple low speed application next to any standard bearing will offer the needed support strength - if that drive has one at all.

> Were external disk drives ever stacked vertically?

It has been used in any combination you may think of.

- Horizontal side by side like in a DEC RX01/02 - as that will need less HE in a rack

[image]

- Horizontal above each other like the Atari 815

[image]

- Vertical side by side like IBM's 6360 8" drive

[image]

- Vertical above each other in an Amstrad PCW8512 ('borrowed' from [Chromatix' answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12133/6659) - to finally fill this slot)

[image]

- Or even both like with a Heathkit H17 case where two dives were mounted horizontal side by side, but when a third drive got added they where turned vertical to fit the case.

[image] [image]

- Heck, they where even Computers mouting them both way at the same time:

[image]

- And then there was the DEC RX-50 dual drive, used in PCs to be placed either as desktop (with the drive horizontal) or tower (now vertical), whatever fits the desk.

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: I'm disappointed to see that you've not included any examples of them being oriented vertically *and then stacked on top of each other*

Comment: @Valorum I'm so sorry, there is a DEC machine doing exactly this, but I couldn't find any worthwhile picture so far. Shame on me.

Comment: The Vobis one designed by Colani still makes me uncomfortable

Comment: @Valorum, Those last two computers (they look like Rainbow 100A to me);  the ones pictured are fitted with a hard drive and a dual floppy, but could be fitted instead with two dual floppy drives (i.e. four floppy drives) stacked in the same configuration you mention.

Comment: @Valorum [This case](https://www.techpowerup.com/151316/lian-li-announces-the-hammer-pc-90-chassis) albeit relatively modern, and for internal drives, has _three_ drives, vertically orientated, mounted atop one another!

Comment: It was common for PET's to stack the dual drives (if you had more than one)  on top of each other and daisy chain them using GIPB

Comment: For "any combination you can think of" I think you're missing an *upside down* photo proof ;)

Comment: @tofro err ... not really sure what that is supposed to be - but I'm pretty sure there is a total obscure machine that used them exactly that way :))

Answer (score 17):

Yes; this was standard procedure for at least the BBC Micro:

[image]

Including for third-party drives:

[image]

Presumably because two drives arranged that way were only just taller than the machine itself:

[image]

Comment: To my mind, the initial reason for stacking two half-height 5 1/4" drives on top of one another like that was because they take up the same space as a single full-height drive. Compare the BBC-branded AND02 twin half-height drives in your third photo with the AND-01 single full-height drive pictured at http://chrisacorns.computinghistory.org.uk/8bit_Upgrades/Acorn_AND01_100KFDD.html . They appear to have used the exact same outer casing for both models.

Comment: Though it should also be noted that some drive sets for the BBC Micros put the drives side-by side, see http://chrisacorns.computinghistory.org.uk/Computers/Master512.html and http://chrisacorns.computinghistory.org.uk/Computers/BBCBI3.html

Comment: Not _any_ orientation. The OEM manual for the Shugart SA400 minifloppy drive is very clear: [_"Do not horizontal mount with PCB down."_](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_shugartSA478_3019449/page/n25).

Comment: @Kaz I've got a Cumana unit with two 5.25" drives side-by-side, but not in a plinth as in the pictured examples. The cable isn't quite long enough to put it in a convenient position, which makes it really awkward to use.

Answer (score 8):

1. I don't think your claim that never happened is generally true
2. It makes a lot of sense to put drives side by side when you want to place the drive set between computer and CRT (like many Apple users did). That wouldn't work well with stacks.
3. Especially [twin 3 1/2" drives](https://bboah-hardware.de/cgi-bin/showhardware.cgi?HARDID=783) were very often sold as vertical [stacks](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FDgrw6sLV4AA7Ik3.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Ffoone%2Fstatus%2F1011886120483737601&docid=Q5q-lnLhtpE4fM&tbnid=8mSE4KPdokp2EM%3A&vet=12ahUKEwiNuozHxrbhAhVKblAKHSLQCmU4ZBAzKFQwVHoECAEQVQ..i&w=1200&h=900&itg=1&client=firefox-b-d&bih=941&biw=1564&q=floppy%20disk%20dual%20&ved=2ahUKEwiNuozHxrbhAhVKblAKHSLQCmU4ZBAzKFQwVHoECAEQVQ&iact=mrc&uact=8). But some vendors also did the same with the [larger drive sets](https://martinjonestechnology.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/img_6556.jpg)
4. If you look at earlier drives, 2 x 5 1/4 full-height drives stacked on top of the other really would be awkward to handle (but, see [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ULTRA-RARE-Atari-815-Dual-Disk-Drive-prototype-/172515706186?hash=item282abcc54a%3Ag%3ASJkAAOSw-0xYlkWn&nma=true&si=ilBj1a0DvoIrqUTdXXODu6D7IxM%253D&orig_cvip=true&nordt=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557)) - that simply looks clunky.

Other than that, I don't see a technical reason why you wouldn't want to stack drives on top of the others. The frames of 5 1/4 drives are mostly aluminium castings, so stable enough to stack, and heat really shouldn't be a problem with floppy drives.

[German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBM-Diskettenlaufwerke#/media/File:Cbm-laufwerke2.jpg)  seems to know how to stack Commodore 4040 drives as well. You simply need to have enough of them ;)

Comment: "Heat really shouldn't be a problem with floppy drives." That's true but the power supply generates heat.

Comment: @traal but you won't stack the power supply?

Comment: On the top or the bottom? Passive or active cooling?

Comment: For Apple 's It was very common to have two drives stacked vertically and  a CRT on top of the base unit

Answer (score 7):

One configuration I think Raffzahn missed so far was two *independent* drives stacked on top of each other. That was the recommended method for multiple Amstrad 3" drives:
[image: amstrad cpc464]

(Image source: [Gallery - Category: CPC464 - Image: CPC464 (b) setup - Roland in the caves](http://www.retrocom.org/gallery/amstrad/computers/cpc464/cpc464-b-setup-roland-in-the-caves-468))

Comment: Common for CBM PET drives I can remember having a stack 3 or 4 high of the various drives.

Answer (score 6):

In the TRS-80 Model I and Model II ecosystems, floppy drives normally had the *disk* oriented vertically. This made the drives "tall rather than wide", and placing multiple drives side-by-side worked well.
[image]

In the Model III, two horizontal drives were stacked vertically in the main housing, to the right of the CRT (and above the numeric keypad).

[image: Model III]
<sub>(source: [nightfallcrew.com](https://www.nightfallcrew.com/wp-content/gallery/radio-shack-trs-80-model-iii-microcomputer/IMG_0890.jpg))</sub>

Comment: While interesting, this is not really an answer to the question

Answer (score 6):

Here's an Amstrad PCW8512, which featured two 3" hard-shelled floppy drives, both vertically oriented *and* vertically stacked, built into the side of the monitor.  A very space-saving design.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since the question specifically references Commodore 8-bit drives, I thought I'd add a few details here.

The PET/CBM series dual drives used both configurations internally: While the 5.25" drives (like the 4040 in the question) were stacked horizontally

[image: CBM 4040 / Source: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_4040]

the 8280 stacked two 8" drives vertically:

[image: CBM 8280 / Source: http://www.6502.org/users/andre/petindex/drives/gallery/8280.gif]

These units were, in turn, designed to be stacked vertically (and built like tanks to they could withstand each others weight):

[image: Stack of CBM drives / Source: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBM-Diskettenlaufwerke]

The *only* Commodore 8bit drives *not* designed to be stacked vertically were those in the 1541-style case (1540, 1541, 1551, 1570, SFD 1001). Here, Commodore put a transformer + linear regulator power supply (heavy, hot) into a comparatively small and not very sturdy case (see https://www.bayerischer-stenografenverband.de/fotos/2017_BM_Computermuseum.jpg for a side-by-side). Heat was a problem even without stacking (see e.g. http://cbmmuseum.kuto.de/floppy_vc1540.html). So the slight slant in the case top was probably intentional to discourage stacking.

Commodore solved the heat issue first in the 1571 (switch mode power supply), then in the 1541-II and the 1581 (external power supply). All those again have flat tops and are designed to be stacked.

This picture shows the slant of the 1541 (bottom) and the stackability of the others (1571, 1541-II, 1581, from bottom to top) quite nicely:

[image: 1581, 1541-II, 1571, 1541 / Source: https://www.retro-programming.de/retro-welt-2/hardware/meine-altertumlichen-geratschaften/c64/laufwerke/]

Answer (score 4):

Quite usual disposition on Apple II with 9" monitors.

[image: Apple II+]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course external disk drives were often stacked.   The LaCie 'Joule' external
disk tower was a vertical stack/rack for drive modules,[depicted here](https://web.archive.org/web/19971017230143/http://www.lacie.com/prodjd.html) and many
external disk cases were given interlocking features (feet or molded plastic
shapes that would keep a stacked unit from sliding off).

Comment: those don't seem to be floppies, though.

Comment: Until USB came along, no Mac supported multiple externals except SCSI (usually hard disks, optical, or super-floppy); there was only a connector for a single floppy  external, so no stacking issue there.

Comment: the question wasn't limited to Macs, though

Comment: @scruss The answer isn't limited to Macs, either; SCSI allowed a half dozen externals, or more, on any suitably equipped computers; SGI, DEC, Sun, IBM, all had SCSI externals.